# I have no idea what to do next for a vowel counter

Tags: c#

I'm stumped on why I'm getting 25 when I type in my name for the program. It's supposed to count the vowels and last time I checked chase only has 2. Here's a [picture of assignment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4aJaGug-OR1UW1VeVlXY19BS2s/view?usp=sharing) as well.

```
/* Program      :   Ch5Ex12a - CountVowels
 * Programmer   :   Chase Mitchell
 * Date         :   11/18/2015
 * Description  :   User's vowels are counted
 */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Ch5Ex12a
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int bacon=0;
            string Phrase;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter in letters");
            Phrase = Console.ReadLine();





                foreach (char a in Phrase)

                    bacon += 1;

                foreach (char e in Phrase)
                    bacon += 1;

                foreach (char i in Phrase)
                    bacon += 1;

                foreach (char o in Phrase)
                    bacon += 1;

                foreach (char u in Phrase)
                    bacon += 1;



            Console.WriteLine(bacon);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. I'd ask my teacher but he's ill and these are due soon

Comment: in your sample a e i o u is just variable name, not the charchter value

Comment: The answer is obvious if you use a line by line debugger. Are you sure this is C#?

Comment: I love your optimism that simply naming a variable like the letter would make the computer magically know you meant that letter. This is not an insult, from a layman's point of view why *shouldn't* it work that way. It's kind of a nice window on how a new programmer would think. Anyway, well done for having a stab at it and coming for help with some code you've written, we often just get the assignment and "please do it for me" (Also +1 for naming your variable `bacon` - but please don't do this if you continue your programming career!)

Comment: poke's answer will fix your problem, so I won't address your question but rather your variable names. I know you said you're a new student so for the purpose of a classroom it doesn't ultimately matter, but you should really really get in the habit of using good variable names. Instead of `bacon` you should name it something like `vowelCounter` or something at least *remotely* indicative of the purpose of the variable. `Phrase` is a good one for the string you read in, but common convention is to start with a lowercase so `phrase` would be better.

Comment: You should simplify your programm: 
foreach (char vowel in Phrase)
 bacon += 1;

Comment: Wow thanks guys i didn't know I was so wrong. also the bacon thing is just something I do for these school programs for variables i don't know what to call them. I obviously need to learn more on my own since I'm top of my class apparently... (Wasn't sarcasm)

Answer (score 9):

```
foreach (char a in Phrase)
    bacon += 1;
```

What do you think this does? This does *not* iterate over all `'a'` characters in `Phrase`. Instead, it iterates over **all** characters in `Phase` and counts them. It’s just that the variable name that gets assigned each character in each iteration is called `a`. But that has nothing to do with the content.

You tried to do something like this:

```
foreach (char c in Phrase)
{
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        bacon += 1;
}
```

You should also check for upper-case characters; either explicitly or by converting the `Phrase` into lower-case first. You could do that by looping over `Phrase.ToLower()` instead of `Phrase`.

Comment: Would "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c) be faster/better?

Comment: `OR` to `||` or this won't compile

Comment: @PatrickHofman Wow, what the hell was going on in my head there. Sorry, fixed!

Comment: @TaW contains is heavy, uses indexof()... I'm not sure it'll be faster, but it would be easier to write/read

Comment: @TaW ``switch(c){case 'a':case 'e':case 'i':case 'o':case 'u':case 'A':case 'E':case 'I':case 'O':case 'U':bacon++;break;}`` is the best choice. * joking *

Comment: @poke OP did mention he took some VB prior to C#, so you probably just had that in your head when posting your answer :)

Comment: @sab669 It’s probably more because I just worked on Python question before with lots of `and`s and `or`s ;)

Comment: @sab669 Using a switch construct in a for-i loop should be the fastest, but yeah... it looks awkward with so many cases.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this code:

```
foreach (char a in Phrase)
    bacon += 1;
```

What it does:

1. It iterates (goes over) the `Phrase` variable and gets out every character after another.
2. It assigns the current value to a variable named `a`.
3. It adds one to `bacon`. (Note: no check is made!)

I guess you think it did get all `'a'` out... It doesn't.

There are some ways to overcome this. [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33781287/993547) has put one in already. Another option would be this [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb397906.aspx) `Count` statement:

```
char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
int vowelCount = Phrase.Count(c => vowels.Contains(c));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why is your variable called `bacon`? You should call it something meaningful like `numVowels`.

Second, the `foreach` statement doesn't work like you're expecting it to.

```
foreach (char a in Phrase)
    bacon += 1;
```

This does not say that "for every A in the phrase, add one to bacon". What it actually says is, for each *thing* in the phrase (in this case each character) store it in a temporary variable (which you're calling a, e, i, o and u) and do *something* (in this case: add one to your counter). So the reason you're getting 25 is you're doing 5 identical loops that each add one to the counter for each letter (5 x 5 = 25).

What you actually want to do is a single `foreach` and compare each character to see if it's a vowel:

```
foreach (char character in Phrase) {
    if (character == 'a' || character == 'e' || ... ) {
        numVowels += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, why check each character individually, it would be better just to define a String and then check if it contains the character. Readability decreases when you have 5 different OR conditions.

Comment: Because he's just a kid starting out and I wanted to make it as simple as possible for him. This doesn't need to be production quality code....

Comment: Also, I’d personally say checking for vowels is simple enough that 5 or conditions are not complicated at all, and you might argue that it gives a better performance too.

Comment: +1 Because so many people on StackOverflow ignore the fact that question akswers are very clearly students or otherwise newbies  and post overly elaborate solutions that -- while they solve the question-- don't really teach anything, or are far beyond what they're working on. Baby steps, people!

Answer (score 0):

Establish a vowelList array. If the vowelList contains c then increment the count of bacon.

```
String vowelList = "aeiou";
foreach (char c in Phrase)
{
    if(vowelList.Contains(c))
        bacon += 1;
}
```

Comment: `vowelList.Contains(c)` doesn't work. It has to be a `char[]` for that.

Comment: Alternatively `c` would have to be a string ;)

Comment: In line with the OP's assignment criteria, using Char.ToLower on c would count both upper and lower case vowels.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to normalize your data, rather than trying to check for instances of both upper and lower case. Either by converting the vowel list to upper/lowercase or the character to upper/lowercase.

Comment: ``vowelList`` isn't a ``List`1`` nor an array

Comment: It was in revision 1 @BinkanSalaryman (click edit ... mins ago to see)

Comment: Oops, I used the term vowel list loosely, when it is actually a String which contains a list of vowels.

Comment: @TheShaman Still not precise enough :P It's a string which lists vowels by its content. Not to be confused with the CLR type ``List`1``.

Answer (score 0):

Well, loop over the string and count. To avoid *mess* (and *errors*) in your code, try do not *cram all the code* into one `Main` method.

```
  // Model: what is/are vowel. 
  // So if you're asked to count vowels in, say, Russian you know what to change 
  private static HashSet<Char> s_Vowels = new HashSet<Char>() {
    'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', // is 'w' considered being vowel?
    'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 
  };

  // Routine: count vowels in a given phrase
  // No input/output here, so it will work in WinForms, Command Line, ASP... 
  private static int CountVowels(String phrase) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phrase))
      return 0;

    int result = 0;

    foreach (char letter in phrase)
      if (s_Vowels.Contains(letter))
        result += 1;

    return result;
  }

  // Input/output
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter in letters");
    string Phrase = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("It contains {0} vowels.", CountVowels(Phrase)));
  }
```

**Edit**: your initial code has a line `using System.Linq;` if you put it *intentionally*, and you're allowed to use *Linq*, the routine can be *shorten*:

```
  private static int CountVowels(String phrase) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phrase))
      return 0;
    else
      return phrase.Count(letter => s_Vowels.Contains(letter)); 
  }
```

Comment: `w` is not a vowel in English. Sometimes `y` sort of is, but their tutor excluded this.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko From the Visual Studio 12.0 C# class template I can tell that the ``using`` directives are most likely generated, and in this case the author is using .NET 4.0. I can't imagine this was put there intentionally by a rookie.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily overly complex for someone who is clearly a new student. I often love reading your answers, you're a far more experienced programmer than I am, but for a poster who is clearly just starting out in their comp sci degree offering up a hash set as a solution is extreme amounts of overkill.

Comment: @sab669: well `HashSet<T>` is a standard data structure as well as `List<T>`, `Dictionary<K, T>`; and it's designed for using like that, so it's worth mentioned. Technically, an array `Char[] s_Vowels = new Char[] {'a', ..., 'U'};` will do, but, IMHO, students should learn to use *right* data structures.

Comment: In time, sure. But when the student in question is at a place where they think `char a ... bacon += 1` is the same as `char a ... if (a == 'a') bacon+=1`, I don't think now is the time to start introducing some of the more sophisticated types / structures. Also, in VS '08 - '13 (all I have installed to verify against), `System.Linq` is included by default in a console application.